# python functions and subfunctions using default parameters

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this assignment and when run the code it prints extra output. Can any one tell me where I messed up the code and how to fix it? Thank you! And I sometimes want to indent and backspace a couple of lines at the same time, how do I do that?

**Assignment**
Create a program which has a main function and a subfunction called `tester`. The `main` function prompts user for an `input` `"Write something (quit ends): "` and sends this `input`to the subfunction as a parameter.

Define the subfunction `tester` so that it has one parameter called `givenstring`, which has the default value `Too short`. If the user input is less than 10 characters, the program uses the default value and if 10 or more, it prints the `usergiven` `input`. If the user inputs `"quit"`, the program is terminated. When working correctly, the program will `print` out something like this:

```
>>> 
Write something (quit ends): what?
Too short
Write something (quit ends): What do you mean?
What do you mean?
Write something (quit ends): Ok thats it
Ok thats it
Write something (quit ends): I am out of here
I am out of here
Write something (quit ends): quit
>>>
```

The easiest way of testing the length of a string is by using the function `len()`.
Example output

Write something (quit ends): what?
Too short
Write something (quit ends): What do you mean?
What do you mean?
Write something (quit ends): Ok thats it
Ok thats it
Write something (quit ends): I am out of here
I am out of here
Write something (quit ends): quit

**My code:**

```
while True: 
def tester(givenstring="Too short"):
    result=len(wrote)
    if result<10:
        print(givenstring)
    else:
        print(wrote)

wrote=input("Write something (quit ends): ")


if wrote=="quit":
    break
else:
    tester(wrote)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    tester()
```

**my code's output:**

> ```
> Write something (quit ends): what?
> what?
> Too short
> Write something (quit ends): What do you mean?
> What do you mean?
> What do you mean?
> Write something (quit ends): Ok thats it
> Ok thats it
> Ok thats it
> Write something (quit ends): I am out of here
> I am out of here
> I am out of here
> Write something (quit ends): quit
> ```

**Output should be like the following:**

> ```
> Write something (quit ends): what?
> Too short
> Write something (quit ends): What do you mean?
> What do you mean?
> Write something (quit ends): Ok thats it
> Ok thats it
> Write something (quit ends): I am out of here
> I am out of here
> Write something (quit ends): quit
> ```

Comment: To be honest with you, this assignment doesn't make much sense. Functions can have default values for their parameters, but they're used when no argument is passed for that parameter, not when some condition about the argument is true. Unless you're supposed to do the length check in `main()` and not pass the input string if it is less than 10 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one argument to `tester`:

```
def tester(givenstring="Too short"):
```

So when you call

```
tester(wrote)
```

You replace the `givenstring` with `wrote`.

Change the function definition:

```
def tester(wrote, givenstring="Too short"):
```

It would be more efficient to move the function definition *outside* the `while` loop, too.

Also, you call `tester` without any arguments `if __name__ == "__main__"`. You could wrap your whole `while True` loop in `def main():` and call *that* instead:

```
def tester(...):
    ...

def main():
    while True:
        ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks now it's working and do you know how I can indent or forward a couple of lines at ones when working with python code? thanks again!

Comment: Depends on OS and IDE. In the default IDLE, it's Ctrl-[ and Ctrl-]

Answer (score -1):

seemingly, your code structure would not work, and you want to use raw_input instead of input. try this -

```
def tester(givenstring):
    result=len(givenstring)
    if result>10:
        print(givenstring)
    else:
        print("Too short")

def main():
    while True:
        wrote=raw_input("Write something (quit ends): ")
        if wrote=="quit":
            break
        else:
            tester(wrote)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `raw_input` is Python 2 only. In Python 3 (which I suspect the questioner is using, given the parentheses after `print`), `input` works like `raw_input` used to.